# yii2 binds redirect to each link after first request

Tags: redirect, yii2

```
public function actionDone($id)
{
    if ($model = $this->findModel($id)) {
        $model["status"] = 3;
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['test/index']);
        }
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

It works only for the first time for each link. After that its just redirects to the **'test/index'** without doing anything. Seems like browser (or smth else) remember, that if we open, for example, page **site.com/?r=test/done&id=2** it should redirect to **'test/index'** anyway.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

I even tried put **die();** in the beginning of the method - anyway it redirects to **'test/index'** until I use different link with another ID.

Thanks!

Comment: if model is found using $id and $model->save() returns true, then it will be always redirect to test/index. You have to add some extra condition to avoid it.

Comment: you should add you model validation code at least and what do you mean by **After that its just redirects to the 'test/index' without doing anything** you are setting the `status` to 3 which is updated for the first time the next time it will remain 3 how do you know it is not saving, if it wasnt it would show you a blank page.

Comment: I know it because I changed status to 1 in phpmyadmin, and when I open page for the second time - its not working anymore. Its just redirects to 'test/index' and status remain 1. Even if I remove all the code inside actionDone - it still redirect to 'test/index'

Comment: well cant tell much until you add `model` code and `findModel()` as it is unlikely to happen with only the above-given code, and do you have any `beforeAction` defined inside your controller, and you dont need the else part `else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }`

Comment: See what `curl -v {URL}` gives you so you can see what else might be going on.

Comment: Did you try calling your action via POST method?